# Elastic Beanstalk - Docker Platform with ECR - Specifying a tag via environment variable

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I am looking at using Elastic Beanstalk + ECR to manage deployments.

```
FROM <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repoName>:<TAG>
ADD entrypoint.sh /
EXPOSE 8080 8787 9990
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This is working if I hard code the entire FROM .. But What I really want is to pass the tag as an environment variable. I want to pin the version.

What I am trying to do is have Code Build  build, deploy, test, and (if all goes well), promote the artifact to a STAGE repo.. where it will be promoted to a Prod after another set of tests.

Then our terraform can pass the commitId to deploy.

I want to avoid deploying latest tag because we want to control when the change gets release and there is potential for auto-scale event to pull it before it has been tested.

My optimistic attempt to add ${GIT_COMMIT} illustrated that the Dockerfile's FROM  does not interpret Environment Variables. And a few passes with `sed` suggested that all the file coying beanstalk does ( to onDeck / staging / current ) probably would not be wise.

I am wondering if people have had success addressing similar goals with Beanstalk/ECR.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `ARG` in your `Dockerfile`. Passing an argument to a `Dockerfile` should work. Take a look at [Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact). Your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
ARG GIT_TAG
FROM <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repoName>:${GIT_TAG}
ADD entrypoint.sh /
EXPOSE 8080 8787 9990
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Then you should be able to build your image using something like this:

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_TAG=SOME_TAG .
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. and read the docs you pointed me at!.
I assume the --build-arg is when we publish the image?

Comment: Yes, it is used to pass an argument during building an image. It is also possible to pass arguments to an entrypoint script while building a container.

Comment: This does not appear to work in my situation: I have a hunch that this is because when beanstalk does the deployment it ends up doing a pull   of <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repoName>:${GIT_TAG}

Docker is complaining about the format if the image ref. I assume this is because it does not like ${}  portions of the tag.

Comment: There are othere aspects of the development process where the information you provided will be helpful.. like locally when building.. were we can run `docker build`

Comment: This sounds like an escaping char issue. It works fine when you try it with simple strings; for example `FROM ubuntu:${TAG}` and passing `focal` as the argument.

Comment: With beanstalk... I cannot control how the final image is built on the instance:  I have no hook into  calling `--build-arg GIT_TAG=SOME_TAG .`  when `SOME_TAG` changes.  

best I could do is docker run {image}  -eSOME_TAG=${SOME_TAG}   - That does not seem too helpful.

Still working with the resource you provided to see if it is has what I am after.